# .NET 4 The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have

- IIS 7.5
- Server 2008
- ASP.Net 4.0 web site
- enabled IIS services and static content
- reverted to parent the staticFile under handler mappings
- registered the asp.net again in command prompt(the regiis.exe thing)
- done all the advice that generally covered.

But this could not solve my problem.

Comment: -In IIS manager i've added my website address under sites, stopped default web site and started mine.This helps me and web site is running successfully

Comment: Then I have compared the properties of Default Web Site with other site and found difference in HttpHandlers. There are nbr of Handlers present in Default Web site while missing in mine. I added asp.net -isapi handler by copying properties from default web site but there is the difference that my added handler was local while Default web site it shows integrated. Then I select handler, right click and use option revert to parent. it adds all required handler and Now site is running properly

Comment: I think you need to describe your original intent. _Typically_, you don't have to do any of these mappings unless you're doing something "special" (hence, the question, what were you trying to accomplish in the first place)?

Answer (score 0):

go into iis choose your site go to handler mapping on the left pane click revert to parent it should fix your issue.